# ng build --prod producing same files in dist folder

Tags: angular, build

I deleted the dist folder and tried

```
npm cache clear 
npm install 
ng build --prod
```

I have deleted a component, but I keep getting Component is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.

What else should I do to clear the cache and actually rebuild the app?

Comment: And the obvious question, does it work without `--prod`?

Comment: code please, GitHub or something else

Comment: The other obvious question: are you sure you're not still *importing* this "deleted" module somewhere in your code?

Comment: @DanielB, yes, it works

Comment: @paulsm4, I have checked several times. I'm not importing it anywhere else

Comment: Check if you have any unused component in your application and that is not declared inside the module.